# UILabel Font Clipping iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I'm loading a font and setting it on a label like this

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyMonoFont" size:150.0];
label.font = font;
label.text = "TOBY"
```

However, it seems to clip or hide the bottom part of the text (as shown below). It works fine with another font I tried. Both fonts are TTF and are "valid" according to the "validate" action in Mac's Font Book app.

[image]

There are some constraints (it's auto layout) but as I say, anther font seems to cope ok.

Thanks for any hints.

**EDIT**: Bit of an update; updating the label frame size doesn't make a difference (if I have auto layout on). I'd like to keep auto layout on but suspect its clashing / resizing the frames. I wonder if theres a way for them to play nicely.

Comment: Increase the height of the label. That font looks like it's significantly taller than most.

Comment: In interface builder do you mean? I tried in code with label.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); but it didn't affect anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increase the height of frame of label according to font size of your label .

```
label.frame = your frame.
```

Comment: Updating with something like label.frame = CGRectMake(time.frame.origin.x, time.frame.origin.y, time.frame.size.width, 250); seems to set the height (checked with NSLog(@"Height %f", time.frame.size.height); but it doesn't repaint. Would I need to force some kind of refresh after?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `sizeToFit` method of UILabel to achieve this.

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

or manually compute the label's size and set the label's frame [Dynamically changing font size of UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865458/dynamically-changing-font-size-uilabel)

Comment: I tried the sizeToFit with no luck, I'll try your other suggestion next

Comment: Sure, I've tried changing the height but the autoresize squashes things again (if I switch this off, the height works and the font will display fully, but I havn't figured out how to arrange things without autolayout). The sizeToFit seems to make no difference.