# How to shrink the size of the text inside a label

Tags: swift, tttattributedlabel

Im trying to get text to fill the entire bounds of a label no matter how long or short the text string is. I want the largest possible font size without any truncation or clipping.

I set up my label like so:

```
var messageTitle = TTTAttributedLabel()
messageTitle.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
messageTitle.font = AppTheme.largeMessageFont()
messageTitle.verticalAlignment = .Bottom
messageTitle.numberOfLines = 0
messageTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
messageTitle.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
```

And set the various constraints to set the size of the label to be 250 x 250.

I'm pretty sure this used to work. The label text now gets truncated if it is long when it should be shrinking the size of the text

Comment: an example in objective-c is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865458/dynamically-changing-font-size-uilabel and it should be easy to adopt to.

Comment: That looks like it changes the size of the label's frame? My label must remain the same size

Comment: you can iterate your font size until it matches the given label size based on this code

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you are using the default initializer `init`, which will not correctly set up many internal properties of `TTTAttributedLabel`. You must use `initWithFrame:` even if you specify `CGRectZero` for the initial frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font into maximum font size then add this attribut

```
    theLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    theLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5 //this is the minimum scale factor, set it as small as you want
```