# Automatic scaling of fonts in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

I'm a UX designer working with a handful of developer teams. We're having an issue with what I believe to be a lot of hard coded values for fonts (as well as other things). The end result being that if a user changes their font size on their phone, or if the app is loaded on a smaller phone like a 4 or 5, the whole design breaks.

I am just beginning to read up on it, but it seems that there's a proper way to build screens and handle text so that it adapts to both device size and user font settings without things breaking (like text overlapping, text boxes bumping into each other, or just flat out text sizes not changing/adapting when they should.)

It seems that the new San Francisco font helps somewhat with this, although we have not been able to implement it yet (again, too much hard coded stuff).

I wonder if someone could lay out the proper strategy for handling text at multiple device sizes and user settings. I am assuming it has something to do with Adaptive Layout. I need to be able to go back to the team and intelligently have the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property of `UILabel`. For details have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865458/dynamically-changing-font-size-of-uilabel).

Comment: Thanks for the link. That solves for one type of instance. I'm more asking about what the overall strategy is for app design, so that all your fonts are dynamic. When I open the Apple News app, and change my font settings to large or small, or look at the app on the iPad or smaller phones, all the text scales so that it looks right. How is that accomplished?