# Setting font size based on line height in NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField where the font used can be changed by the user.

Although the font's point size remains the same, the actual height of the font is much bigger for some fonts. This means if the user changes the font to 'Zapfino' for example, most of the text is cropped. I would like it so the text in the box always looks roughly the same size.

Also the line height seems to change depending on which font is used meaning they don't line up well and sometimes get pushed down and the bottom gets cropped off.

How can I keep the text size and line height looking the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need NSTextField which is using single line. You can do it in *Attributes inspector* by checking ***Uses Single Line Mode***.

How to do it:

[image: Single mode]

And now Your text will be like this:

[image: example]

**Do programatically:**

To change NSTextField height programatically by font size or scale the text to fit the bounds [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908704/get-nstextfield-contents-to-scale/2911982#2911982).

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I increase the font size the text box stays the same height and the bottom is cropped off.

Comment: It's now moving the text up and cropping the top off. Are there some settings I'm missing?

Comment: I'm also not sure this will work if the font is changed using code. I'm using bindings to do this.

Comment: If You want to use the same size font all the time then You need to change the height of NSTextField by changing Line Break to Word Wrap (then You can change height to whatever height You want). And If user can change height You can try to change NSTextField height programatically by font size or scale the text to fit the bounds example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908704/get-nstextfield-contents-to-scale/2911982#2911982.

Comment: I've changed the height pragmatically using the question you suggested. That has sorted me out. Could you add it to your answer so I can mark it as accepted. It's a bit hidden in the comments.

Comment: @Richard I updated the answer as You suggested. I'm glad that this solved Your problem.